# Совмещение двух псевдоклассов в CSS3

Tags: css3

Как совместить для одного параметра в CSS :first-child и :after
Так вообще можно делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно так делать)

```css
div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  margin: 12px;
}

div:first-child{
  border-color: red;
}

div:first-child:after{
  content: "Ну да,";
}

div:nth-child(2):after{
  content: "Так можно";
}

div:nth-child(3):after{
  content: "Делать";
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Блин, спасибо большое! Я маялся часа 2,  делал и так :first-child:after и так  :after:first-child
А благодаря Вам, понял - забыл content: "";

Comment: ай да Миша, ай да шельмец ^_^